# Testing twisted protocol

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, twisted

I have a very basic client and server protocols developed using `Twisted`. Twisted allows to [unittest](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/trial.html) them independently and provides nice testing utils such as the `StringTransport` for this.

However, let's say I want to test the protocol works fine. For instance, I want to test that when the server receives a certain message, it will reply to the client in some specific way. What is the best way to do that using `trial` and the utils in Twisted? I am currently launching processes to run them, but then I lose the access to their objects and I need to dump their states in a file to validate the correct behaviour. I don't think this is a clean way to do it. It would be much better to use a `StringTransport` that simulates a TCP connection from the client to the server. How do twisted developers normally test this?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question:  ``It would be much better to use a StringTransport that simulates a TCP connection from the client to the server``.  There should be enough info on the unit test docs for you to get started.  Avoid subprocesses and threads as you will undoubtedly drive yourself crazy (I know I did)

Comment: @notorious: thanks for the comment. Yes, I'm trying to do that. When one of the ends sends data, I flush the `StringTransport`, and manually feed the contents to `dataReceived` at the other end. This has obvious limitations for more complex interactions between the client and the server. My question was whether there is a standard way to solve this problem...

Comment: ``When one of the ends sends data, I flush the StringTransport, and manually feed the contents to dataReceived at the other end`` is pretty much the "standard" way of doing it. Once again you've answered your own question :). You're basically simulating incoming and outgoing data (for the most part) so by simply checking ``StringTransport`` and pumping data into ``dataRecieved`` does just that. If you have a more complex situation then please explain it.

Comment: So, for example, let's say I have a long sequence of messages from client to server and the other way around, and I just want to test that the final state, after the sequence has run, is correct. I can't just pass to `dataReceived` all messages as there are too many. I thought to use a something like `task.LoopingCall` to flush and feed `dataReceived` periodically but doesn't seem right. If there was at least an event in `StringTransport` to flag when there is new data and could callback a function that passes it to `dataReceived`....